# Elastic Search :: Sort by date with documents with higher score

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, search

I am wondering how I can increase the probability of newer documents (based on a publishedDate value) without actually having to sort on a multi_match query:

```
 {
 "from": 0,
 "size": 12,
 "_source": false,
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "multi_match": {
           "query": "Best Movies",
           "fields": [
             "publishedDate^1",
             "headline^2",
             "subheadline^3",
             "metaDescription^4",
             "metaTitle"
           ],
           "type": "best_fields",
           "lenient": true,
           "tie_breaker": 0.3
         }
       }
     ],
     "filter": {
       "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
             "term": {
               "status.keyword": "published"
             }
           },
           {
             "term": {
               "taxonomyPaths.verticals.keyword": "primaryvertical"
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

What happens if I add:

```
"sort": [
    {
      "publishedDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
```

it completely loses the documents with the actual higher score. How can I get those documents with a higher score value but stack the newer entries "publishedDate" on top of the results?

Comment: You can sort on publishedDate and _score "sort": [
        { "publishedDate ": { "order": "desc" }},
        { "_score": { "order": "desc" }}
    ],

Comment: You should sort first by _score and then by PublishDate so you will get high score document sorted by the date. Another option would be to use script score to edit score value of query by running a script.

Comment: I've tried:

    sort: [{ _score: { order: 'desc' }, publishedDate: { order: 'desc' } }],

but still some older documents take precedence of newer ones